# takeOrdered not working in Pyspark for reverse order

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

When I tried to get the top 3 elements it works fine , but on reverse order its not working

```
sc.textFile("/user/sachinkerala6174/inData/movieStat").takeOrdered(3)
```

The above statement works fine

When tried the bellow its getting errored out

```
sc.textFile("/user/sachinkerala6174/inData/movieStat").takeOrdered(3,key=lambda x: -x)
```

Input data

```
196 5   3   881250949
186 5   3   891717742
22  1   1   878887116
244 1   2   880606923
166 3   1   886397596
298 4   4   884182806
115 2   2   881171488
253 4   5   891628467
305 4   3   886324817
6   4   3   883603013
62  2   2   879372434
286 1   5   879781125
200 2   5   876042340
210 4   3   891035994
224 2   3   888104457
303 5   3   879485318
122 3   5   879270459
194 2   2   879539794
```

Throwing an error as

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/heapq.py", line 427, in nsmallest
    result = _nsmallest(n, it)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'unicode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails as the lambda functions tries to calculate the negative value of a string. In PySpark (unlike Scala and Java) there is no method to reverse the sorting order of `TakeByOrdered`, however, you achieve the same by adding a line number to each input line using zipWithIndex. This will give you the following output format:

```
[('196 5   3   881250949', 0), ('186 5   3   891717742', 1), ....]
```

You can then use the long index as a sortkey allowing you to take the last three lines of your input file:

```
lastLines = sc.textFile("/user/sachinkerala6174/inData/movieStat").
zipWithIndex().takeOrdered(3,key=lambda x:-x[1])
```

Using `map` you can then get back the last three lines only:

```
map(lambda x:x[0], lastLines)
```

Comment: It Worked @Jaco - Thanks a ton

Comment: >>> lastLines = sc.textFile("/user/sachinkerala6174/inData/movieStat")
>>> getLast = lastLines.zipWithIndex().takeOrdered(3,key=lambda x:-x[1])
>>> getLast
[(u'194\t2\t2\t879539794', 17), (u'122\t3\t5\t879270459', 16), (u'303\t5\t3\t879485318', 15)]